# Kendo UI Scheduler and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler, kendo-datasource

Trying to make work Kendo UI with ASP.NET MVC. 
I can use ready-to-work toolkit, but it will tie front-end to back-end; that's inappropriate, so I'm doing all manually. 
I've bound datasource

```
dataSource: {
                batch: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "http://192.168.0.34/FRINGE/api/tasks",
                        dataType: "json"
                    },
```

modified schema

```
schema: {
    model: {
        id: "TaskID",
        fields: {
            taskId: { from: "TaskID", type: "number" },
            title: { from: "Title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
            start: { type: "date", from: "Start" },
            end: { type: "date", from: "End" },
            description: { from: "Description" },
            ownerId: { from: "OwnerID", defaultValue: 1 },
            isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" }
        }
    },
    parse: function (responce) { /*debugger;*/ }
},
```

and wrote a simple controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Tasks(int? id)
{
    //«data» type is List<Tasks>
    if (id.HasValue) 
        return Json(data.SingleOrDefault(x => x.TaskID == id.Value), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    else 
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Which produces data like

```
[{"TaskID":1,"Title":"Action","Start":"\/Date(1425009600000)\/","End":"\/Date(1425013200000)\/","Description":"Action time","OwnerId":1,"IsAllDay":false},{"TaskID":2,"Title":"Dinner","Start":"\/Date(1425034800000)\/","End":"\/Date(1425038400000)\/","Description":"Dinner time","OwnerId":1,"IsAllDay":false}]
```

But nothing works. Checked schema and data on Telerik Kendo UI Dojo, and all good there. I think, problem in controller declaration due to some params lack. 
What I've missed?

Comment: Are you using `WebApiController` or simple `Controller` because if you use such url `"https://192.168.0.34/FRINGE/api/tasks"` this means you try to use web api. Please show your WebApiConfig.cs or ensure you specified right route to this action: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: No, it's just simple Controller from MVC.

Comment: https://192.168.0.34/FRINGE/api/tasks works and returns correct JSON data. Problem, I think, in Controller parameters. I'm trying to connect scheduler to MVC without Kendo MVC, e.g. without Kendo DataSourceRequest and etc.

Comment: Can you show the html with the binding to that action ?

Comment: Whole cshtml is there http://jsfiddle.net/eefwcf8n/

Comment: Are you sure you are not doing cross-domain requests? If yes you must use `dataType: "jsonp"` in the transport configuration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72040/discussion-between-rexilion-and-arman-stepanyan).

Comment: if you set a breakpoint on your controller's Tasks method, does it ever get called? one thing I do notice is that you're binding one field to "OwnerID" but are returning objects with OwnerId (lower-case d)

Comment: Yes, use Fiddler or F12 tools to see where the request for the data is made, and whether the data does come back to the browser.  Make sure the F12 console does not show errors.  If those look fine, then install the Kendo Chrome extension, then view the datasource to see if it has any data:  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/telerik-kendo-ui-chrome-i/npcmgpnfknjmndbbakdhchgibaajnlpe?hl=en

Comment: Thaks for suggestions, corrected params. 
Kendo Extension provide follows http://i58.tinypic.com/2119q3p.png

Comment: Yes, at least GET is called, but `id` is null.

Comment: What happens when you remove `?` from the declaration `(int? id)`

Comment: @ArmanStepanyan you can remove the id parameter entirely; also: you should use the [change](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-change) and error events and log the passed argument; and you should probably remove the filters until you get it to read properly at least

Comment: Removed `id`. 

Kendo Linter shows 
`http://localhost/FRINGE/Home/Scheduler:114,24
Unknown option: id

http://localhost/FRINGE/Home/Scheduler:115,24
Unknown option: fields`

Comment: the linter doesn't help, it just looks at your source code; did you add a change and error event handler to the data source, then inspect the argument?

Comment: It's will not be bad if you provide some example of that.

Comment: there are examples in the links: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#events-error and see comment above for change; then you can log e.status (for error handler) or e.items (for change)

Comment: `e.status` with error-binding return is `undefined`.
`e.items` with change-binding returns a complex object which have two `ht.extend.init` with my parsed JSON data, `length` object (value is 2) and some other functions and proto.

Comment: actually, what do you do in the schema.parse method? your fiddle shows it does nothing..it has to return the data

Comment: Oh. Oh-oh. `schema.parse` I'm used when tried to bind to datasource first time. After writing this, I'm changed datatype and schema. 
After removing `schema.parse` I've got events shown. 
They bunch downloaded, and controller(and I'm) still know nothing about filtration, paging and etc, but this is a good begging. 
Thank thou, Developer.
Please post your answer and take the reward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining a [parse](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.parse) method in your schema which does nothing. You have to remove it or return data from it:

```
parse: function(response) {
  return response;
}
```